# How can I do a callback from FireBreath to JavaScript

Tags: c++, plugins, callback, firebreath

Code sample:

```
bool MirrarOrnaments::onMouseDown(FB::MouseDownEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *) 
{
  if(evt->m_Btn == FB::MouseButtonEvent::MouseButton_Left) 
  {
    //from here i need to function in my JavaScript with argument of FB::variant_list_of(evt->m_x)(evt->m_y)); 
  }
}
```

Is it possible?
Was trying simply return variant_list to use it in JS,

but it need to be bool anyway cos of:

```
BEGIN_PLUGIN_EVENT_MAP() 
EVENTTYPE_CASE(FB::MouseDownEvent, onMouseDown, FB::PluginWindow)       
END_PLUGIN_EVENT_MAP()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to have a callback into JavaScript you first need to pass a callback as input to your JSAPI plugins.

you can do this as follows:

in PluginTestAPI.cpp

```
registerMethod("SetCallback", make_method(this, &PluginTestAPI::SetCallback));

int PluginTestAPI::SetCallback(const FB::JSObjectPtr& callback)
{
  m_CallBack = callback;
}
```

in PluginTestAPI.h

```
class PluginTestAPI 
{
  FB::JSObjectPtr* m_pCallback;
  int SetCallback(const FB::JSObjectPtr& callback);
```

and then in the JavaScript pass this function when you setup:

```
 function myJSCallback (params)  {
 }

 myplugin.SetCallBack(myJSCallback);
```

Then you can call this callback from your C++ code:

```
bool MirrarOrnaments::onMouseDown(FB::MouseDownEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *) 
{
  if(evt->m_Btn == FB::MouseButtonEvent::MouseButton_Left) 
  {
    //from here i need to function in my JavaScript with argument of    
    m_pCallback->Invoke(FB::variant_list_of(evt->m_x)(evt->m_y)); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Also you can fire events as described in http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Firing+Events+from+JSAPI

Comment: Also note that if you're going to pass FB::JSObjectPtr by reference it should be const FB::JSObjectPtr& (make sure it is const).  Otherwise you could accidentally cause some issues, even if it does compile. (I edited the post to reflect that)

Comment: you are right taxilian, thanks for the edit, this is in fact the way it's done in code and you are also right about the event, I just picked a single answer, not 5 ;)

Comment: Was trying to fire it as described in those docs, compiling but not working for some reason, anyway thank you, will test it later.

Comment: Underlines m_CallBack as not defined.  
If m_pCallback meant to be there, than `= : cannot convert from "const FB::JSObjectPtr" to "FB::JSObjectPtr *"`
Changed last one to `FB::JSObjectPtr` without `*`, compiling, but is that correct?
And isn't there must be `Invoke("place for function", FB::variant_list_of(evt->m_x)(evt->m_y));` and with `"myJSCallback"` on that place, I guess?

Comment: Compiled, but, sadly, no reaction on mouse click on page with plugin.